# Using Startup class in ASP.NET5 Console Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is it possible for an ASP.NET 5-beta4 console application (built from the ASP.NET Console project template in VS2015) to use the `Startup` class to handle registering services and setting up configuration details?

I've tried to create a typical `Startup` class, but it never seems to be called when running the console application via `dnx . run` or inside Visual Studio 2015.

`Startup.cs` is pretty much:

```
public class Startup
{
  public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
  {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.AddJsonFile("config.json");
    configuration.AddJsonFile("config.{env.EnvironmentName.ToLower()}.json", optional: true);
    configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables();

    this.Configuration = configuration;
  }

  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    services.Configure<Settings>(Configuration.GetSubKey("Settings"));

    services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(this.Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));
  }

  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
  {
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(minLevel: LogLevel.Warning);
  }
}
```

I've tried to manually create the `Startup` class in my `Main` method, but this doesn't seem like the right solution and hasn't so far allowed me to configure the services.

I'm assuming there's some way for me to create a `HostingContext` that doesn't start up a web server but will keep the console application alive. Something along the lines of:

```
HostingContext context = new HostingContext()
{
  ApplicationName = "AppName"
};

using (new HostingEngine().Start(context))
{
  // console code
}
```

However so far the only way I can get this to work is if I set the `HostingContext.ServerFactoryLocation` to `Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener`, which starts up the web server.

Comment: Is there such thing as an ASP.NET 5 Console Application? Surely it's either an ASP.NET Core Application, or a .NET Core Console Application?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you're looking for is the right idea, but I think you'll need to back up a moment.

Firstly, you may have noticed that your default `Program` class isn't using static methods anymore; this is because the constructor actually gets some dependency injection love all on its own!

```
public class Program
{
    public Program(IApplicationEnvironment env)
    {            
    }        

    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, there aren't as many of the services you're used to from an ASP.NET 5 hosting environment registered; thanks to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn913182.aspx) and the `IServiceManifest` you can see that there's only a few services available:

> Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.IAssemblyLoaderContainer
>   Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.IAssemblyLoadContextAccessor
>   Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.IApplicationEnvironment
>   Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.IFileMonitor
>   Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.IFileWatcher
>   Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.ILibraryManager
>   Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.ICompilerOptionsProvider
>   Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.IApplicationShutdown

This means you'll get the joy of creating your own service provider, too, since we can't get the one provided by the framework.

```
private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

public Program(IApplicationEnvironment env, IServiceManifest serviceManifest)
{
    var services = new ServiceCollection();
    ConfigureServices(services);
    serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
}

private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
}
```

This takes away a lot of the magic that you see in the standard ASP.NET 5 projects, and now you have the service provider you wanted available to you in your `Main`.

There's a few more "gotchas" in here, so I might as well list them out:

- If you ask for an `IHostingEnvironment`, it'll be null. That's because a hosting environment comes from, well, ASP.Net 5 hosting.
- Since you don't have one of those, you'll be left without your `IHostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName` - you'll need to collect it from the environment variables yourself. Which, since you're already loading it into your Configuration object, shouldn't be a problem. (It's name is "ASPNET_ENV", which you can add in the Debug tab of your project settings; this is not set for you by default for console applications. You'll probably want to rename that, anyway, since you're not really talking about an ASPNET environment anymore.)

Comment: Thanks this helps, once the `ServiceProvider` has been created as you've pointed out, I can pass it into the `DbContext`. Is it safe to make the `ServiceProvider` static? I'm assuming there's no way for it to be automatically attached like inside ASP.NET5 Hosting projects.

Comment: Once you use your `IServiceProvider` to create something, it can get an instance of the `IServiceProvider` through DI, and propagate itself. It's generally considered bad practice to have a singleton service provider; it breaks testability, for starts.

Comment: I've used the `ServiceProvider` to create a `DbContext`, if I create the context with the provider it works, but when I create a second `DbContext` without passing along the provider it fails. Is there some place I need to manually register the `ServiceProvider` in order for it to be accessible automatically?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean; perhaps you could post another question relating to EF7 to show your code and error?

Comment: It's not related to EF7 specifically, I'm just wondering how to register the `IServiceProvider` to DI so it can be automatically used by the EF7 / ASP.NET5 classes that support it, as of right now it only works if I pass the `IServiceProvider` instance around.

Comment: @MattDeKrey Has this changed for the RC?

Comment: Some of the namespaces have changed, but this is still the same here. To specify your own services in a console application, you'll need to build your own `IServiceProvider` as given in the second code block as far as I'm aware. (You can even construct it by using your `Startup` class if you explicitly access it!)

Comment: Main is static once again since RC1: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/113

Comment: Ugh. I missed that one. That makes me a little sad that they're encouraging the use of the app-level statics. Thanks for calling it out, @Chris!

Comment: @MattDeKrey I liked the DI thing too :(.