# .Net core 2 console appsettings transform

Tags: appsettings, .net-core-2.0

I am trying to add appsettings transformation to a .net core 2 console application e.g.

- appSettings.json
- appSettings.Test.json
- appSettings.Prod.json

I have found the following code works for asp.net core:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: 
true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: 
true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

However, I don't know how to get `env.EnvironmentName` because there is no `IHostingEnvironment` in a console app.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Startup class in ASP.NET5 Console Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30257710/using-startup-class-in-asp-net5-console-application#30259936)

Comment: This is not a duplicate because IApplicationEnvironment has now been removed
https://github.com/aspnet/PlatformAbstractions/issues/37

Comment: And `Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.PlatformServices.Default.Application` doesn't contain any environment information

Comment: Good point well made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't find anything else so using preprocessor directives for now

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if

```
public Startup()
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: 
true)
```

> ```
> #if RELEASE
> ```

```
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.Release.json", optional: 
true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```